# In AngularJS's ngShow or ngHide, or conditional, what happens when a property doesn't exist? (such as for a.b.c.d or !a.b.c.d)

Tags: angularjs, ng-show, ng-hide

Let's say in the condition of AngularJS's `ngShow`, what if a property doesn't exist?

For example, if `vm.foo` is `1`, then what if in the HTML, there is a

```
<div ng-show="myCtrl.foo.bar.wa.la">
    hello
</div>
```

and what if it is

```
<div ng-show="!myCtrl.foo.bar.wa.la">
    hello
</div>
```

Example at: https://jsfiddle.net/4yg2ocy6/1/

(If it is pure JavaScript, it will raise an exception)

I suspect that

```
myCtrl.foo.bar.wa.la
```

is treated by AngularJS as the same as:

```
(myCtrl.foo && myCtrl.foo.bar && myCtrl.foo.bar.wa && myCtrl.foo.bar.wa.la)
```

and

```
!myCtrl.foo.bar.wa.la
```

is the same as

```
!(myCtrl.foo && myCtrl.foo.bar && myCtrl.foo.bar.wa && myCtrl.foo.bar.wa.la)
```

but I can't find any documentation about it.

Another possibility is that it treats `(myCtrl.foo.bar.wa.la)` as one unit, if Angular can evaluate it, then return the result, but if it raises an exception, catch it and return false.  So for `!myCtrl.foo.bar.wa.la`, it will treat it as `!false` and therefore is `true`.

Is there a more definite spec for this?

Answer (score 3):

#### The short (and sweet) answer

`myCtrl.foo.bar.wa.la` will evaluate to `undefined` which doesn't trigger `ngShow`.

#### The long answer

One important thing to note from [Angular Expressions vs. JavaScript Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression):

> **Forgiving**: In JavaScript, trying to evaluate undefined properties generates ReferenceError or TypeError. In Angular, expression evaluation is forgiving to undefined and null.

This means that something like `a.very.long.reference.which.does.not.exist` won't throw an error and **will evaluate to undefined**. See this example:

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.typeOf = function(value) {
      return typeof value;
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
    <div>{{ vm.typeOf(a.very.long.reference.which.does.not.exist) }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, to answer your questions. Internally, both [ngHide](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngShowHide.js#L334) and [ngShow](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngShowHide.js#L172), use a basic check to see if the expression is true or not. They do something like: `if (expression) { // do this } else { // do that }`.

Since both `ngHide` and `ngShow` are triggered when the `expression` is truthy, and that `a.very.long.reference.which.does.not.exist` evaluates to `undefined`, is clear to see why they aren't triggered when a property doesn't exist.

**Some expressions and their evaluation:**

```
undefined ? 'truthy' : 'falsy' // 'falsy'
null ? 'truthy' : 'falsy' // 'falsy'

// Booleans
true ? 'truthy' : 'falsy' // 'truthy'
false ? 'truthy' : 'falsy' // 'falsy'

// Numbers
1 ? 'truthy' : 'falsy' // 'truthy'
0 ? 'truthy' : 'falsy' // 'falsy'
0.00001 ? 'truthy' : 'falsy' // 'truthy'
NaN ? 'truthy' : 'falsy' // 'falsy'

// Strings
'something' ? 'truthy' : 'falsy' // 'truthy'
'0' ? 'truthy' : 'falsy' // 'truthy'
'' ? 'truthy' : 'falsy' // 'falsy'

({}) ? 'truthy' : 'falsy' // 'truthy'
[] ? 'truthy' : 'falsy' // 'truthy'
(new Date()) ? 'truthy' : 'falsy' // 'truthy'
```

Comment: Your quote is correct, Angular uses the `$watch` service on the value of `attr.ngHide` (ngHide is just an example). Watch in turn uses the `$parse` service to parse the passed angular expression and that expression follows the rule you quoted above. [ngHide source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngShowHide.js#L326) [watch source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L387). for future reference in the docs clicking 'view source` takes you to the actual source so you can see exactly what is happening.