# AngularJS - ng-if if there is a specific value in array

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

I would like to trigger `ngIf` when there is a specific value in an array inside the scope.

So I have this on my scope:

```
var orders = [{
    "order_no": 1,
    "color": ["blue", "pink", "red"]
}, {
    "order_no": 2,
    "color": ["yellow", "blue", "white"]
}];
```

I would like to have an `ngIf` that shows one element if, for example, yellow is present in one of the color arrays (given that I would not know the data scope in advance, but knowing the structure in advance).

The only way I have found to do that would be when knowing the structure of the scope in advance, so fx `ng-if="orders[1].color[0] === 'yellow'"`

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can call the [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method of the `color` array inside your HTML template. This way, you don't need to pollute the `$scope` with additional methods.

Here's how: `ng-if="order.color.indexOf('pink') !== -1"`

**Note:** don't forget that [expressions in AngularJS are different](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). One key factor to remember is that they are forgiving.

> **Forgiving**: In JavaScript, trying to evaluate undefined properties generates ReferenceError or TypeError. In Angular, expression evaluation is forgiving to undefined and null.

This means that something like `myCtrl.foo.bar.wa.la` will evaluate to `undefined` which doesn't trigger `ngIf`. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35918996/in-angularjss-ngshow-or-nghide-or-conditional-what-happens-when-a-property-do/35919425#35919425).

Comment: I will mark this as correct as the answer is more detailed, and having it in the html seems more straightforward to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could do this as a function expression

```
ng-if="hasYellow()"

$scope.hasYellow = () => $scope.orders.some(
  order => order.color.indexOf("yellow") > -1
);
```

Depending on the size of `orders` and how often it changes, it may be more efficient to just have a `hasYellow` property and update that when `orders` is changed.